# can't find dev/video0 on android tablet

Tags: android, android-ndk, v4l2

I want to get the data of camera in C level, so I am trying to run some V4L2 code on my android tablet. In that situation, I need to open the device and get its capacity, and in V4L2 the device can usually be like dev/video0, dev/video1...

Anyway, I can't find that on my tablet. I've tried Samsung, Motorola, Nexus, none of them works. I also tried some cellphones and I did found that in the cellphones.

Could anyone tell me why? Or do these files have different names in tablets?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is different for NDK but did you add CAMERA permission to Android Manifest?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: I did add that. To execute the v4l2 code I need to open the device. The device's name is usually like dev/video*. I just have trouble finding the camera name of the tablets.